# ZFS: How could my file got permanently corrupted?

Tags: ubuntu, zfs

I'm trying to understand what could have gone wrong.

**for context:**
I have a **mirrored** set with **3 drives** and **non-ECC memory**. Not sure what else to share.

I was under assumption that having a **3-way mirror would keep me relatively secure** from incidental corruptions, like failing drives, or that memory corruption would be recoverable (from one of 2 remaining disks).

But I'm probably misunderstanding.
Can anyone explain what could have gone wrong so I can secure myself for the future?

```
$ sudo zpool status -v
  pool: dozer
 state: ONLINE
status: One or more devices has experienced an error resulting in data
    corruption.  Applications may be affected.
action: Restore the file in question if possible.  Otherwise restore the
    entire pool from backup.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-8A
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 8h36m with 1 errors on Sun Jan  6 02:12:32 2019
config:

    NAME                                          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    dozer                                         ONLINE       0     0     1
      mirror-0                                    ONLINE       0     0     2
        ata-WDC_WD40EFRX-68N32N0_WD-WCC7K1ZKZLYK  ONLINE       0     0     2
        ata-WDC_WD40EFRX-68N32N0_WD-WCC7K6VCAZXL  ONLINE       0     0     2
        ata-ST4000DM000-1F2168_S301LW48           ONLINE       0     0     2

errors: Permanent errors have been detected in the following files:

        /dozer/path/to/my/file
```

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance, favour returned, question upvoted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do understand that if any single non-RAIDed drive has a failure, you lose data and the same is true if one of the non-ECC memory chips has a failure: *you lose data*.

And even if you have:

- dual processors
- dual NICs
- dual hard drives
- ECC memory
- High-availability fail-over servers in a different data centre on a different continent

...any kind of uncorrectable error (Bug, human, Electro-Magnetic Pulse, .. ) can *still lead to data loss*.

**And that's why, with all this nifty technology, *we still have multiple off-line backups today*.**

<sub>**Note:** On-line backups / Data replication to a secondary Data Centre can be corrupted too in this way</sub>

Comment: When on doubt, backup. If still in doubt, backup again.

Comment: Thanks! Yea, I do have a backup, just trying to make sure I haven't set it up in a wrong way or something. I'm also willing to accept the fact of having non-ECC, hence backup.

Comment: Let me get one thing straight, please. If something messed up in, say, `ata-ST4000DM000-1F2168_S301LW48`, then zfs would recover from one of the other drives, right? But if the corruption happened in memory, then mirror doesn't help anymore. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. @BartekChlebek  (For some or other reason, I never replied to the last comment...)